# R Subset duplicates in a row and return duplicates and index

Tags: python, r

I have the dataframe show below:

```
> df
  c1 c2 c3 c4
1  1  0  1  2
2  2  1  4  3
3  3  3  5  4
4  4  3  6  5
5  5  4  7  7
```

I am trying to subset the data frame to return the duplicate elements on a row-by-row basis. That is to return the row numbers and the corresponding elements which have duplicates in that row. Something like this:

```
index  duplicates
1       1
3       3
5       7
```

I have tried using the line of code below:

```
dfc <- apply(df, 1, function(x) duplicated(x))
dfc <- t(dfc)
df[dfc]

[1] 3 1 7
```

I would like to have the corresponding row index of the duplicate elements return as well. Especially in such a case of more than two elements having duplicates in a row.

Comment: Using `which(table(row(df), as.matrix(df)) > 1L, arr.ind = TRUE)` will return the [row, col] indices of duplicated elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the example (assuming that there will be only pair of duplicate per row).  We extract the duplicate elements for each row with `apply` and `MARGIN=1`.  The output will be a `list` as some rows doesn't have any duplicates and are of length 0.  From the `list` output, create a `data.frame` by getting the 'index' of 'l1' that have `length` not equal to 0 and the 'duplicates' from `unlist`ing the 'l1'.

```
l1 <- apply(df, 1, FUN  = function(x) x[duplicated(x)])
data.frame(index = which(lengths(l1)!=0), duplicates = unlist(l1))
#  index duplicates
#1     1          1
#3     3          3
#5     5          7
```

Comment: thanks a lot for this! it works. When I have more than one duplicate element on a row. i.e row 1, column c2 is changed to 2. Is there a way to adapt this code to show elements 1 and 2 ad duplicates in index 1?

Comment: @T-Jay One way would be to `paste` the elements together in the `list` i.e.`l1 <- lapply(l1, paste, collapse="_")` and